# Can someone explain what does <? super T> mean and when should it be used and how this construction should cooperate with <T> and <? extends T>?

Tags: c#, java, generics, generic-programming

I'm using generics rather long time but I've never used construction like `List<? super T>`.

What does it mean? How to use it? How does it look after erasure?

I also wonder: is it something standard in generic programming (template programming?) or it's just a java 'invention'? Does c#, for example, allow similar constructions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This construct is used when you want to consume items from a collection into another collection. E.g. you have a generic `Stack` and you want to add a `popAll` method which takes a Collection as parameter, and pops all items from the stack into it. By common sense, this code should be legal:

```
Stack<Number> numberStack = new Stack<Number>();
Collection<Object> objects = ... ;
numberStack.popAll(objects);
```

but it compiles only if you define `popAll` like this:

```
// Wildcard type for parameter that serves as an E consumer
public void popAll(Collection<? super E> dst) {
    while (!isEmpty())
    dst.add(pop());
}
```

The other side of the coin is that `pushAll` should be defined like this:

```
// Wildcard type for parameter that serves as an E producer
public void pushAll(Iterable<? extends E> src) {
    for (E e : src)
    push(e);
}
```

**Update:** Josh Bloch propagates this mnemonic to help you remember which wildcard type to use:

**PECS** stands for *producer-extends, consumer-super*.

For more details, see [Effective Java 2nd Ed., Item 28](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/generics.pdf).

Comment: Effective Java is great, but I still don't have 2nd edition ((

Comment: @Roman you can download the chapter about Generics from the link I added :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'll read it. Don't you know are there any other 'sample chapters' available for free?

Comment: This is the best answer. Joshua Bloch in Effective Java 2nd Edition actually proposes a mnemonic:

    "PECS stands for producer-extends consumer-super"

Comment: Why doesnt' Vb.Net has a c#/Java super generic equivalent?

Answer (score 4):

This is called "bounded wildcard". It's very well explained [in the official tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html).

As stated in the tutorial, you thus know that the list contains objects of exactly one subtype of `T`

For example `List<? extends Number>` can hold only `Integer`s or only `Long`s, but not both.

Comment: `List<? extends Number> numbers = Arrays.asList(1,5L);` compiles just fine. So the list `numbers` is holding both Int's and Long's. What am I  missing from the last line of your answer?

Answer (score 4):

These things are known, in type theory, as *variance*, with `<? extends T>` being a co-variant notation, and `<? super T>` being a contra-variant notation. The simplest explanation is that `?` may be replaced by any type extending `T` in the co-variant notation, and `?` may be replaced by any type which `T` extends in the contra-variant one.

Using co and contra-variance is much more difficult than it may seem at first, particularly since the variance "toggles" depending on the position.

A simple example would be a function-class. Say you have a function which takes an `A` and returns a `B`. The correct notation for it would be to say that `A` is contra-variant and `B` os co-variant. To understand better how this is the case, let's consider a method -- let's call it `g` -- which receives this hypothetical *function* class, where *f* is supposed to receive an `Arc2D` and return a `Shape`.

Inside `g`, this `f` is called passing an `Arc2D` and the return value is used to initialize an `Area` (which expects a `Shape`).

Now, suppose that the `f` you pass receives any `Shape` and returns a `Rectangle2D`. Since an `Arc2D` is a also a `Shape`, then `g` won't get an error passing an `Arc2D` to `f`, and since a `Rectangle2D` is also a `Shape`, then it can be passed to `Area`'s constructor.

If you try to invert any of the variances or swap the expected and actual types in that example, you'll see it fails. I don't have the time right now to write down this code, and my Java is quite rusty at any rate, but I'll see what I can do later -- if no one is kind enough to do it first.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Generics FAQ has a good explanation about Java generics. Check the question [What is a bounded wildcard?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#FAQ103) which explains the usage of construct "? super T" in good detail.