# Generic types vs using a superclass

Tags: java

What exactly is the difference between using  and using the Superclass as the type itself? For ex:

```
class Shape {}
class Circle extends Shape {}

List<Shape> void operate (List<Shape> shapes) {...}
<T extends Shape> void operate (List<T> shapes) {...}
```

What are the differences between the last two lines above in the way we define an arraylist that can contain shapes?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html  (this is beside your code not being valid java)

Comment: That document adds to my confusion a bit... in those examples, what is the point of defining <U extends Number> when you could simply have U = Number itself??

Comment: I think the document explains it pretty well and if it's unclear, perhaps you should start earlier in the tutorial. As I said, what you've written isn't even valid code so your misunderstanding of generics might be more basic than you think. This might also help you, especially if you follow up the references to _Effective Java_. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486689/java-bounded-wildcards-or-bounded-type-parameter

Comment: @pvg This document explains why to use bounded generics vs unbounded generics, but OP is asking why use bounded generics vs no generics at all. The given example uses <U extends Number> void foo(U u). This is a poor example because it's logically equivalent to void foo(Number n); hence OP's confusion.

Comment: @EvanDarke I've read it, thanks. It was for additional context on top my first two refs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following two method declarations:

```
public static <T extends Number> void sort1(List<T> list>) {
// Do stuff
}

public static void sort2(List<Number> list>) {
// Do stuff
}
```

Now recall the Integer is a subclass of Number, but List<Integer> is not a subclass of List<Number>.

```
List<Number> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
sort1(numbers);    // Valid: Number extends Number
sort1(integers);   // Valid: Integer extends Number
sort2(numbers);    // Valid: Type matches exactly
sort2(integers);   // Invalid: integers is not an instance of List<Number>
```

In this case, bounded generics make sense because if you can sort a list of numbers you should be able to sort of list of Integers too. Here's a case where you can't use T extends Number:

```
/** Adds a Double to a list of numbers */
public static void foo(List<Number> list) {
   list.add(5.0);
}
```

It's valid to pass in a list of numbers and add a Double, but it's invalid to add a Double to a list of Integers. This is why List<Integer> is not a considered a subclass of List<Number>.

Answer (score 0):

If you define this class:

```
class NumberList<E extends Number> {
    private List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
    // various methods here
}
```

Then you can use it like these examples:

```
// List can only contains Integer objects
NumberList<Integer> intList = new NumberList();

// List can only contains Double objects
NumberList<Double> doubleList = new NumberList();

// List can contains mix of any Number object, e.g. Integer, Double, BigDecimal, etc.
NumberList<Number> numberList = new NumberList();
```

But this is not allowed:

```
NumberList<String> stringList = new NumberList();
```

Answer (score 0):

`List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();`
will be a container for all `Shape` type objects including the subtypes. You can add Circle or Square or any other shape object to that list. Also, assigning `shapes = new ArrayList<Circle>()` will not work.

When you say there is a method

```
public static <T extends Shape> List<T> getShapeList(T...ts) {
    return Arrays.asList(ts);
}
```

and now you make method calls this like :

```
List<Circle> circleList = getShapeList(new Circle(3), new Circle(1), new Circle(2));
List<Square> squareList = getShapeList(new Square(4,2), new Square(10,4), new Square(5,1));
```

It allows you to use this method to return lists of specific sub class type objects. The method is bounding the generic parameter to be of type Shape or anything that extends it.