# Java inheritance with parameterized Lists

Tags: java, inheritance, parameterized

I have a strange problem with inheritance and I don't understand why it should not work:

```
public interface A {  }

public interface B extends A {}


public class C {
void test() {
    ArrayList<A> foo = new ArrayList<B>();
    }
}
```

But compiling gives me the following error

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<B> to ArrayList<A>    C.java  /bla/src/de/plai/test   line 8  Java Problem`

Comment: you should probably grab this [Generics](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf) tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ArrayList<? extends A> foo = new ArrayList<B>();
```

A List of A is not the same that a List of B because you could not guarantee consistency of contents in the list.

Namely, if it were possible you could insert an item of type A in a list that was instantiated only to contain B elements.

Of course the above declaration will prevent you from writing any elements into the list. This is a read-only declaration.

Also it is a good OOP principle to declare the variables as interfaces, not implementations:

```
List<? extends A> foo = new ArrayList<B>();
```

Answer (score 7):

It may seem counterintuitive at first, but even if class `B` is a subclass of `A`, a `List<B>` is not a subclass of `List<A>`. I gave a more detailed explanation and example in [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292308/generics-method-signatures-assignments/2292339#2292339) to a similar post. See also [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310449/can-someone-explain-what-does-super-t-mean-and-when-should-it-be-used-and-how/2310473#2310473) for a link to the respective item in *Effective Java 2nd Edition*.

The solution to this problem is using *wildcards*. Thus you should declare your list as

```
List<? extends A> foo = new ArrayList<B>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Was just above to to post the same :) well nevertheless.. the answer is same this should work for you.

```
ArrayList<? extends A> foo = new ArrayList<B>();
```