# cast from List<MyClass> to List<Interface>

Tags: java, object, interface, casting

I think I made some mistake while writing my code.
I have a class MyClass that implements Interface, now I've a method that is generic for List of Interface as a parameter. I want to use my method by passing a List. I can't cast from List to List (that I assumed I could). So, what can I do to make my code work? here an example:

```
List<MyClass> lista = returnMyClassList();
myMethod((List<Interface>) lista); //this doesn't work

//myMethod signature
public void myMethod(List<Interface> struttura);
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Change your method signature to `List<? extends Interface>`. As to why this happens, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612157/java-inheritance-with-parameterized-lists).

Comment: Thanks, your link made me understand the issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use an upper bound of `Interface` for the type: `<? extends Interface>`.

Here's come compilable code that uses classes from the JDK to illustrate:

```
public static void myMethod(List<? extends Comparable> struttura) {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> lista = null;
    myMethod(lista); // compiles OK
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
public void myMethod(List<? extends Interface> struttura);
```

In order to get both `List<Interface>` and `List<MyClass>`

Answer (score 2):

`List<MyClass>` is not a sub type of `List<Interface>` you are getting error.
Accorind to java [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html)

> Given two concrete types A and B (for example, Number and Integer), MyClass has no relationship to MyClass, regardless of whether or not A and B are related. The common parent of MyClass and MyClass is Object

So Change your method signature to

```
   public void myMethod(List<? extends Interface> struttura){
   }
```

and call the method

```
   List<MyClass> lista = returnMyClassList();      
   myMethod((lista);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `public void myMethod(List<? extends Interface> struttura);`. This way you will be able to pass any type that `IS-A` `Interface`. You would like to read about [Polymorpshism and generics](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/27/generics-polymorphism-with-generics/)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast this, because you would make a promise you cannot hold.

When you cast from `List<MyClass>` to `List<Interface>` you take a list containing several objects of type MyClass and vast it to a type that makes (among others) the following promises:

1. `Interface get(int index)`  - you can get an element of thpe Interface (no problem)
2. `boolean add(Interface e)` - you can add any element of type Interface (if it is a subtype of MyClass or not) (this is a problem!)

The second point is problematic, because the underlying List is still a list of `MyClass` and not a list of `Interface` in general. You could still hold a link to the underlying List in a separate variable and could run `get` on that list. If you added an object of type `Interface`, that is not also a `MyClass`, you could get this Non-`MyClass` from the `List<MyClass>`.

As all the other answers and comments have pointed out, the correct solution is the type `List<? extends Interface>`. With this type, you can still get objects of type `Interface` from the list (as a return value of a method call), but you cannot put anything into the list (use as a parameter of a method call).