# Understanding syntax in Java

Tags: java, generics

I would like your help in understanding what this syntax means:

```
class Node<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V>
```

What does the `?` stands for?

And isn't there one `<` missing?

Comment: See also [Can someone explain what does <? super T> mean and when should it be used and how this construction should cooperate with <T> and <? extends T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310449/can-someone-explain-what-does-super-t-mean-and-when-should-it-be-used-and-how/)

Comment: A very good resource about Java generics is Angelika Langer's Java Generics FAQ: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `?` stands for "some unknown type". In this specific case it's `? super K` which means "some unknown type that's a base type of `K`  (i.e. "super class of" or "interface implemented by") .

And no, there's no `<` missing: you have two `<` and two `>`, they match up.

Practically it means that `Node` has two type arguments: `K` which probably represents a key, which must be `Comparable` to itself and `V` which probably represents a value.

Answer (score 0):

the [generics/wildcards](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html) tutorial explains this syntax

Comment: I downvoted this because answers that are **just** a single link [are not considered to be good answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: @Joachim Sauer - right, cut-n-paste is better than the link to the exact answer on the technology owner's site ...

Comment: Who's talking about cut-and-paste? Did you read the question I linked to? The issue has been discussed.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer - the author of the question is confused with the syntax of wildcards in generics that is precisely what the article behind the link I gave explains. I did read the question you gave a link to, and I do believe that being a robot is not the best attitude to develop in yourself. In this particular case a single link IS a good answer.

Comment: @bobah: and it's great if you helped, my personal opinion is something different, but that's no problem. A down-vote is not a personal attack. Obviously at least 2 people think that your answer is good, so you got the upvotes. I don't see the problem.